# RESTful shiro permissions based on data

Tags: java, rest, jersey, shiro

I'm creating a RESTful service with Jersey (2.28) and use Apache Shiro for permission handling. So I used the buildin `HttpMethodPermissionFilter` which creates permissions like `resource:read` or `resource:write`. Now I have the problem that a user may only be allowed to read or write a specific resource and that I would need something like `resource:write:<id>` or `resource:write:<name>` or what ever as identifier.

I thought about extending the filter but at that point - even while I could access the body or the url - I have *no idea* how the data looks like.

Solutions I thought about:

1. Always pass a query parameter in the url, like `/api/resource?id=xxx` and if given apply that parameter for the permission string. But there is no way to tell if the parameter is required or not if both `resource:read` and `resource:read:<id>` exist. The filter might create a wrong permission for the given url. I could apply the filter only to urls where I know it must be the case, but seems all a bit wonky and error prone.
2. Remove the filter and ask for the permissions inside of the requested method.

```
@GET
@Path("/resource/{id}")
public Response getResource(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    if(AuthorizationHandler.hasPermission("resource:read:" + id) {
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Resource GET works").build();
    } 
    // return 403 or handle exception or ...
}
```

Somewhat like that, but it will leave me with exception handling in every method which also seems not much preferable. Maybe I could use an `ExceptionMapper` to handle responses... haven't tried that.

Does maybe someone else have another idea how to solve this efficently or maybe point me to an already existing solution? I'd prefere to use the `@RequiresPermissions("resource:read")` annotation (or a custom one), but could also define the urls / filters in the shiro.ini file `/api/resource/** = noSessionCreation, jwtf, rest[resource]` or I fallback to solution 2 if that's recommended.